# How to introduce bundler concept in ruby 1.8.6 and rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Just I wanted to know whether bundler concept can be introduced in ruby 1.8.6 or does it require ruby 1.8.7 ?.How it can be applied in rails 2.3.8 ?.

Your valuable feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundler requires 1.8.7 (which is pretty ancient and more or less unmaintained at this point).

You can use it with rails 2.3.x - the bundler website has instructions on how to set this up

Comment: Thanks I have been looking for such answer.It would be better to upgrade version actually my client asked to introduce bundler in 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

Really, DO NOT USE the 1.8 ruby series any longer. Compared to 1.9.X it has only disadvantages and is not maintanined any longer. Even gems shouldn't be a problem after all this time since the 1.9 series releases.

Sure, not the exact answer you want to hear, but seriously: upgrade.